# Android Development - Randomization Word Generator

Tags: java, android

So unfortunately, I have not even started to code any of this generator, because in fact I do not know how. I am making a Hangman game as a project for my school smart phone programming class, and my partner and I have started to make a hangman game. I already have a wordlist.txt file feeding into a string array; however, I am unsure how to make it so it randomly picks a word from that array.

If Anyone has any idea on how to do so, it would be graciously appreciated.

Thank You!

Colin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it several different ways. You could assign an `int` variable a random number using `Math.util` or `RandomNumber`. Then loop through your array where `i = randomNumber` and show that word.

[See this stack question for implementation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java)

That's what I would do.

Comment: Thank You. Never thought of using Math.util. Thank you for answering very readily:D